# creating perfect square with inline-block

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering if there's a way to create a perfect square using `display: inline-block` The reason is that I want to place it right next to a text e.g.

```css
.legend {
  display: inline-block;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  width: 1em;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="legend">
    d
  </div>
  <div style="display: inline-block">
    Some legend
  </div>
</div>
```

Right now it still looks kinda rectangular.

Comment: How about adding `height: 1em;`, too?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply specify the div's height, too. Consider the following:

```css
/* The container needs to be relatively positioned */
.container {
  position: relative;
}

/* The legend is absolutely positioned, but in relation to its 
 * container.
 * We also apply a common trick to place it at the vertical center of
 * its parent: position the top bound at 50% of the parent's height.
 * then transform the position to move it up by 50% of its own height. 
 */
.legend {
  display: inline-block;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

/* This div is decisive for the whole thing's height.
 * Since the legend is positioned in an absolute way, we need to make 
 * room for it by moving this div to the right (margin-left)
 */
.legend-text {
  margin-left: 1em;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="legend">
    d
  </div>
  <div class="legend-text">
    Some legend
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well, I'd rather use the default line-height if possible

Comment: @A.Lau Why? Do you want the square to be vertically centered in the line? If you set the width to `1em`, then the according height for a perfect square is undoubtedly `1em`.

Comment: Because you'll notice that it's slightly floating off the floor. Look at it with and without the height and you'll notice a small difference.

Comment: @A.Lau you can of course position the square as you please. I update my answer. Comments in the code will explain what I mean.

Comment: @A.Lau hey, did you try the centering the square as I suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple. add height to `.legend`

```css
.legend {
  display: inline-block;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;// just add this line
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Comment: I'd rather use the default line-height, or at least match it

Comment: okay, so you can fix line height, and adjust the width accordingly